# CSS responsive design overlapping body

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, overlap

The situation is: I'm learning on my own how to make websites. I already know some stuff and now I decided to create one website.
But I have some struggle... I'm trying to make it responsive, ant it kinda works, but footer overlaps content in body when you resize the page...

The idea is to scroll down for the tags when they start to overlap..

I've googled for similar issue and checked threads, tried a lot of things, but still got nowhere :|
Help?...

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

background-image: url(https://umad.com/img/2015/1/dark-geometric-wallpaper-176-205-hd-wallpapers.jpg);

}

/*+++NAVBAR*/
#primary_nav_wrap{
width: 100%;
background:#333;
  margin: 0;
float:left;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{

  background-color: #333;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:500;
    line-height:50px;

    padding:0 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#4CAF50
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#282828
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#333;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
/*---NAVBAR*/


.hometitle span{
  width: 100%;
}

.hometitle h1{
  font-size: 80px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.hometitle h2{
  font-size: 36px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -60px;
}


/*+++TAGS*/
.tags {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.item a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
/*---TAGS*/


.homecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    min-height: 400px;
}


#footer{

position: relative;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 20%;


}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Home</title>
          <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/arturnmk/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="main">


<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>

  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="portfolio.html">Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  <li><a href="projects.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WutWut</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contacts.html">Menu</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>


<div class="homecontainer">


<div class="hometitle">

<span>
<h1>Firtname Lastname</h1>
</span>

<span>
<h2>Thing to say/state</h2>
</span>

</div>






          </div>










</div>




    </body>
    <footer>
      <div class="tags">
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">PTagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTagTagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">TagTagTag</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag16 Tag16 Tag16Tag16</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag15Tag15</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag14Tag14Tag14</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag13</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag12</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag11</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag10</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag9</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag8</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag7</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag6</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag5</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag4</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag3</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag2</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#">Tag1</a></div>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </html>
```

Comment: remove `position: fixed;` from class **.tags** and take the `<footer></footer>` in `<body></body>` tag I think it will be work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You shouldn't have HTML code outside of the `<body>` tag for elements that are meant to be displayed on the page. Your footer should be contained inside the `<body>` tag. You can create a `<div>` to contain the elements which you now have in the body of the document.

2) To avoid the overlapping (considering that you want to keep your existing code structure and CSS) you can set a `margin-bottom` equal to the `height` of your footer to the container of your main content. This approach will work if your footer always has the same height.

3) If your footer needs to change in height, another simple solution (but with drawbacks) is to let the footer stick to the normal page flow, instead of absolutely positioning it to the bottom of the document, and to set a `min-height` to the container of your main content. The `min-height` should be set to ensure that your footer won't be positioned in the middle of the user's screen on pages that are short (that don't have a lot of content in them). The `min-height` on the main content's container will in this case create whitespace below the main content that will push the footer down.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve responsive web design, use CSS3 media queries

Issue for overlap is due to min-height of homecontainer class and fixed position for tags class

Please check the below option using CSS3 media queries
https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vJbqeE

CSS:

```
html{
  height:100%;
}

body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

background-image: url(https://umad.com/img/2015/1/dark-geometric-wallpaper-176-205-hd-wallpapers.jpg);

}

/*+++NAVBAR*/
#primary_nav_wrap{
width: 100%;
background:#333;
  margin: 0;
float:left;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{

  background-color: #333;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:500;
    line-height:50px;

    padding:0 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#4CAF50
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#282828
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#333;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
/*---NAVBAR*/


.hometitle span{
  width: 100%;
}

.hometitle h1{
  font-size: 80px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.hometitle h2{
  font-size: 36px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -60px;
}


/*+++TAGS*/
.tags {
  bottom: 10px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.item a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
/*---TAGS*/


.homecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    min-height: 400px;
}


#footer{

position: relative;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 20%;


}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.homecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
 footer{

position: absolute;
top: 400px;
width: 100%;
height: 20%;


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but is the only issue you have the footer getting in the way?

If I want the footer to stay at the bottom of the screen, I usually do as follows:

```
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    height: however high you want it to be;
    transform: translateY(-100%) ;
}
```

That pushes the footer all the way off your screen on the bottom, but the `transform: translate` pulls it back up exactly the height of the footer.

Comment: Well, now when it overlaps, you need to scroll, but scroll the body. Footer is still on top when you shrink the page. Same on the phone...